# How do I get a relative complement of two string array?

Tags: arrays, perl

```
my @A = ("aa","bb");

my @B = ("aa","cc");
```

It is the same concept as relative complement of Set. (A-B) The output should be "bb". I **do not** want to use any external Modules of Perl, only built in functions of Perl.

Comment: Your code doesn't really make sense. You are creating two Array's, `@A` and `@B`, and then assigning a HashRef to it.

Comment: Additionally, complements make sense for sets, not arrays which have an ordering and allow duplicates. You can create sets and perform set operations using [Set::Scalar](https://metacpan.org/pod/Set::Scalar). I will not reimplement it for you in core Perl, but the source is there to read.

Comment: Perhaps you can explain what you mean by "complement?"

Comment: I think you mean "relative complement"

Comment: Please, have a look at StackOverflow's [Markdown help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). In particular, you can format your code by adding four spaces at the beginning of the line.

Comment: @ysth Yes. you are correct. (@)Everyone The question has been updated based on comment section. (@)Grinnz I saw that already. I only was wanted to use something that requires no additional installation of any external module.

Comment: @Dada Thank you. I did not know those formatting options were available in stack overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
my @A = ("aa","bb"); 
my @B = ("aa","cc");

# make a hash with all the elements of @B as keys
my %B;
@B{@B} = ();

my @complement = grep { ! exists $B{$_} } @A;
```

Comment: `@B{@B} = ();` I did something similar in an answer once and had people complain about it... happy to see I'm not the only one who sometimes uses that idiom when you don't care what the values in the hash are.

Comment: @Shawn There's nothing wrong with it, as long as you know to then use `exists` rather than a truthy check, since it will populate the values as `undef`. Personally I prefer values of 1 just for aesthetics, and the performance difference is usually irrelevant.